# Is Map really a type in Flutter? Unfinished Map declarations break other Map declarations

Tags: flutter, android-studio, types, maps

I understand that in Flutter, I can declare a Map using a map constructor':

eg.

var map_name = new Map();

and then use it:

map_name[key] = value

or using Map literals:

var details = {'Username':'Fede','Password':'pass@123'};

However, I have seen perfectly valid code in Dart such as:

Map<String, int> phoneBook ={
'Fede': 12345678,
'Juli': 5467899,
'Pablo' : 56788654,
};

This kind of declaration can be accepted by the compiler in normal cases:
[code accepted by compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPDkK.png)

but (after hours of debugging) I have seen that not finishing the declaration of one map in this way by not assigning a name for it, the compiler (in Android Studio) will yield an error telling that "Map isn't a type" in other valid declarations, even in other files calling that file where the Map declaration was not finished! That is, the error is quite spread.

[crashed code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvU6K.png)
[map isnt't a type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mx699.png)
In other words, the unfinished declaration of one Map breaks the possibility to declare any other Maps in this way, anywhere linked to that unfinished sentence giving a 'map isn't a type' error. The problem dissappears when you just put a name to the unfinished Map declaration and Maps are treated as types again. So my question is: Are Maps a type for Flutter, or is it just a minor bug?

Comment: Could you post your problematic code?

Answer (score 0):

In your **"crashed code"** picture, i seen that you have not provide name for second map.Your error is kind of **syntax**, please provide correct declaration to make its work. I tried your code in my IDE and its working perfectly.The syntax you tried is totally valid and it should working.
[image: My output]

Comment: Yes, exactly.  My comment was that I have discovered that not finishing the declaration of one Map (for example when you are coding elsewhere, will make all other Maps get that error, and finding that unfinished line gets much more difficult, as all the lines that have a Map get underlined and marked as not a type error.  The same happens with String.  Shouldn't the compiler claim just about that unfinished line and not the all others that are complete and valid code?